# C# wait in between turns without pausing the rest of the script

Tags: c#, stopwatch, pause

My current project has 4 players: 1 human (you) and 3 AI's. It's a recreation of the original Virus game to give an idea. You do a move, than the game ups the current player's turn, check if it's an AI and if so, move it. If not, let the player (you) move. In between all turns I have a timer setup;

```
using Systems.Diagnostics;

//Inside the method.

int timeBetweenTurns = 400;
Stopwatch stpw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
While(stpw.ElapsedMiliseconds < 400)
{
    Application.Update();
}
```

this works for the turn itself, but not for the rest of the code. I have a restart button for example. I have to doubleclick that button in order to run the clickevent. The point is, I have to run the restart method twice since the AI still gets its turn.

How do I make a timer that only pauses after each turn, without disabling elements such as a button?

Comment: You could use multiple threads.  There are many ways to implement threading in C# - see here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2595260/1736047

Comment: The `Stopwatch` class has nothing to do with pausing or multithreading. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you want to execute something periodically use a timer. If you want to pause in a method withoud blocking the UI thread use `await Task.Delay()`

Comment: Thanks, Some code needed to be refactured but it works now :)